# Как заставить vi работать в режиме single-user?

Tags: shell, freebsd, terminal, vi

При загрузке операционной системы FreeBSD (в моём случае -  8.4-amd64) в однопользовательском (single-user) режиме, после перемонтирования файловой системы в режим чтения и записи (rw), когда я пытаюсь отредактировать какой-либо файл редактором `vi` (работающим в single-user mode "из коробки"), я получаю на экране кашу из всего содержимого файла на одной строчке. Редактор как бы работает (на команды отзывается), но пользоваться им невозможно.

При загрузке той же самой ОС в обычный (multi-user) режим, `vi` работает как положено. Как это обойти?

[image: попытка отредактировать /etc/fstab]
[image: проблема при редактировании]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что не все конфиги, считывающиеся при обычной загрузке, читаются при загрузке в однопользовательский режим.

Конкретно эта проблема связана с неправильно установленной переменной окружения `TERM`. Решается набором команды `export TERM=xterm` перед запуском редактора `vi`, решение работает до следующей перезагрузки.

Иногда установка `TERM=xterm` проблему не решает, но `TERM=vt100` срабатывает.